# Authentication restriction using Devise plugin in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Is there anyone experience with Rails Devise plugin? Coz in my project, when the user typed username and password, I have to check in another table whether the user is active. There are two tables, first one is the `user` and the other one `role_membership` in `role_membership` table there's a column named `active_status`. I have to check whether the `active_status = 1` otherwise the user cannot log in to the system. Anyone here knows how to configure the Devise plugin to check the value in another tables. I found some tutorials, but all of 'em mentioning about checking in a field in same table.

Thanks

Comment: Why is the users active_status in the roles table? I'd first move that to the main User object. See this question for your other problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055362/devise-before-authenticate

Comment: Actually the active_status was implemented recently and its actually bound with another table called company. so when a particular user disabled, the company also will be disabled. But your suggestion also be a good solution. I'll think about it as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

modify your User model to include two additional methods

- active_for_authentication?
- inactive_message

see http://pivotallabs.com/users/carl/blog/articles/1619-standup-3-21-2011-deactivating-users-in-devise (NOTE: it is based on an older version of devise, below code should work)

```
class User
  # check to see if a user is active or not and deny login if not
  def active_for_authentication?
    super && your_custom_logic
  end

  # flash message for the inactive users
  def inactive_message
    "Sorry, this account has been deactivated."
  end
end
```

replace your_custom_logic with your specific code for determining if user is active or not

additional link: http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Authenticatable/

Answer (score 0):

My best idea is to override devise session#create method.
In order to do it:

```
#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    #resource.is_active? should be implemented by you
    if resource.is_active?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    else
      #put here your inactive user response
    end
  end

end
```

and in routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions" }
```